# Return aggregate for all unique in a group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

The trouble is this.

Lets say we have a pandas df that can be generated using the following:

```
month=['dec','dec','dec','jan','feb','feb','mar','mar']
category =['a','a','b','b','a','b','b','b']
sales=[1,10,2,5,12,4,3,1]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(month,category,sales)), 
                   columns =['month', 'cat','sales']) 

print(df)

| month cat  sales   |
|--------------------|
| 0   dec   a      1 |
| 1   dec   a     10 |
| 2   dec   b      2 |
| 3   jan   b      5 |
| 4   feb   a     12 |
| 5   feb   b      4 |
| 6   mar   b      3 |
| 7   mar   b      1 |
```

then let's suppose we would like a count of each category by month.

so we go and do something like

```
df=df.groupby(['month','cat']).sales.sum().reset_index()
print(df)
|  month cat  sales  |
|--------------------|
| 0   dec   a     11 |
| 1   dec   b      2 |
| 2   feb   a     12 |
| 3   feb   b      4 |
| 4   jan   b      5 |
| 5   mar   b      4 |
```

But what we'd like to see is:

```
|  month cat  sales  |
|--------------------|
| 0   dec   a     11 |
| 1   dec   b      2 |
| 2   feb   a     12 |
| 3   feb   b      4 |
| 4   jan   b      5 |
| 5   jan   a      0 |
| 6   mar   b      4 |
| 7   mar   a      0 |
```

Where the difference is categories that did not show up in a particular month would still show up just with zero as their total.

It's probable this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it. If you point me in the direction of the question, we'll go ahead and delete this one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Continuing from where you stopped, a combo of [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) will give you your required output:

```
res = (
    df.groupby(['month', 'cat'])
    .sales.sum()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)  # Unstack and fill value for the null column
    .stack()  # Return to groupby form and reset
    .reset_index(name='sales')
)
```

The output of `res`:

```
>>> res

  month cat sales
0   dec a   11
1   dec b   2
2   feb a   12
3   feb b   4
4   jan a   0
5   jan b   5
6   mar a   0
7   mar b   4
```

You can also work with categoricals and set `observed` to False; this will ensure that all possible combinations are presented in the final output.

```py
(df.astype({'month' : 'category',
            'cat' : 'category'})
   .groupby(['month', 'cat'], 
             as_index = False, 
             observed = False)
   .sum(numeric_only = True)
)

  month cat  sales
0   dec   a     11
1   dec   b      2
2   feb   a     12
3   feb   b      4
4   jan   a      0
5   jan   b      5
6   mar   a      0
7   mar   b      4
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) as:

```
df=(
    df.groupby(['month','cat']).sales.sum()
    .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.month.unique(), df.cat.unique()], 
                                   names=['month', 'cat']), fill_value=0)
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
  month cat  sales
0   dec   a     11
1   dec   b      2
2   feb   a     12
3   feb   b      4
4   jan   a      0
5   jan   b      5
6   mar   a      0
7   mar   b      4
```

Comment: good solution, think might be more extensible than others above. suggested an edit, since from_tuples(np.product.... didn't actually work using my dummy code as they were non-numeric. Or at least that's the error I got. Assuming using np.product as well.

Comment: @born_naked the product used here from `itertools` not `numpy`. Please check with itertools product.

Answer (score 4):

Another way without `groupby` but with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and `stack`:

```
df_ = df.pivot_table(index='month',columns='cat', 
                     values='sales', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)\
        .stack().reset_index()
print (df_)
  month cat   0
0   dec   a  11
1   dec   b   2
2   feb   a  12
3   feb   b   4
4   jan   a   0
5   jan   b   5
6   mar   a   0
7   mar   b   4
```